# A limit with an exponent

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have this limit as a homework assignment,
$$ \lim_{x\to+\infty} \left(\frac {x^2 + x + 1} {x +3}\right)^{\frac {1} {x^2+2x+4}} $$
I think it can be solved using the number e, but I don't know how to make it in the form where I use that. It would be of great help if you can explain to me at least the first and the second step. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What did you try ? Please add your attempts to the question.

Comment: I believe it can be solved with the number e, but I don't really know how to start.

Comment: **Hint :** $$\left(\frac {x^2 + x + 1} {x +3}\right)^{\frac {1} {x^2+2x+4}} = \exp \left[\frac {1} {x^2+2x+4} \log \left( \frac {x^2 + x + 1} {x +3}\right)\right]$$

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit more, please?

Comment: Is the hint above more helpful if written this way: $$\left(\frac {x^2 + x + 1} {x +3}\right)^{\frac {1} {x^2+2x+4}}=e^{\frac {\ln\left(\frac {x^2 + x + 1} {x +3}\right)} {x^2+2x+4}}$$Here is your number $e$, after all!

Comment: What don't you understand in my hint ?

Comment: Why do we use a logarithm? And why its base is 10? I understand why the exponent comes in front.

Comment: No, the $\log$ is the natural logarithm (base $e$).

Comment: Okay, why exactly the natural log (ln)?

Comment: Well, what is the definition of the power $a^b$, for real numbers $a$, $b$ ?

Comment: a*...*a, where b is equal to the number of times we multiply a

Comment: Ok, so for example, $a^{\pi}$ equals $a \times .... \times a$ "$\pi$ times" ? What does  "$\pi$ times" mean ?

Comment: I don't know. Does it have any connection with this $ \displaystyle a^{b} = e^{b\ \ln a}\  $?

Comment: Of course it has. $a^b = e^{b \ln(a)}$ is the *definition* of $a^b$. It has no other meaning.

Comment: I didn't know that until now. Thanks. So that what the hint was about. Okay, so the next step would be to calculate the limit $ \left(\frac {x^2 + x + 1} {x +3}\right)^{\frac {1} {x^2+2x+4}}=e^{\frac {\ln\left(\frac {x^2 + x + 1} {x +3}\right)} {x^2+2x+4}} $ of this exponent right?

Comment: Yes. Try to determine the limit of $\displaystyle{\frac {\ln\left(\frac {x^2 + x + 1} {x +3}\right)} {x^2+2x+4}}$, and then you will be able to take the exponential.

Answer (score 3):

First note that for big $x$ we have that
$$  1\leq\left(\frac {x^2 + x + 1} {x +3}\right)^{\frac {1} {x^2+2x+4}} \leq\left({x^2+2x+4}\right)^{\frac {1} {x^2+2x+4}}\to 1$$
for $x\to\infty$ since $x^{1/x}\to1$ for $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

A different way is (using the Hint from TheSilverDoe),

\begin{align}
1\leq\left(\frac {x^2 + x + 1} {x +3}\right)^{\frac {1} {x^2+2x+4}}
&= \exp\left[\frac {1} {x^2+2x+4}\ln{\left(\frac {x^2 + x + 1} {x +3}\right)}\right]\\
&\leq\exp\left[\frac {1} {x^2+2x+4}\cdot{\frac {x^2 + x + 1} {x +3}}\right]\\
&\leq\exp\left[\frac {1} {x^2+2x+4}\cdot{\frac {x^2 + 2x + 4} {x +3}}\right]\\
&\rightarrow 1
\end{align}